# As you click on a button from facebook's privacy

Tags: javascript, facebook

[image]

Good evening, I would like to know how to click on a facebook button, I have tried different ways but I get.

I need to javaScript.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('_54ni _4h7j __MenuItem')[0].addEventListener('click',function(){},false)
```

[image]

Comment: For security reasons, Facebook effectively disables the console.

Comment: and how to do it then

Comment: You cannot easily do that

Comment: I can imagine someone here must know how do

Comment: I don't speak English well

Comment: Search through the page JS and find the function that is called when you click on that button, then you can just call that function.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?